# NextJS i18n main menu _app subpage not translate

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next

I have NextJS v14 and i18n to languages. I want to wrap page content in menu component.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nextjs-i18n-menu-syz54t

In `components/menu.js` I have main menu links and `children` handler.

```
export default function Menu({ children }) {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link href={"account"}>{t("menu.links.myaccount")}</Link>
        </li>
        ...
      </ul>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

In `pages/_app.js` wrap `Component` in `Menu` component:

```
import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next";

import Menu from "../components/menu";

function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Menu>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Menu>
  );
}

export default appWithTranslation(App);
```

[image]

The problem is that the main menu on the subpage is not translated

[image]

Any sugestions, where I make mistake? To be clear, I want to use NextJS in `page` mode not `app` mode